# Matplotlib not imported, script opens plot anyway

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have this simple python code

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL", api_key="censored")

print(df.head())
```

And for some reason when I execute it, it prints out

> 1.7320508075688772
>
> 2.23606797749979
>
> 2.6457513110645907
>
> 3.0

And it also opens up this pyplot https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFdSu.png

And when closing the image it prints out the actual df.head, but also

> [5 rows x 12 columns]

There was no way for that to happen, so I got super confused.

Comment: modules can do their own imports. `pandas` specifically imports matplotlib api for it's `plot` interface.

Comment: @RockyLi Well okay, but I never tell it to do anything that it does. I PRINT out the df.head, I never do any plot showing or any description. And like I said I had the same code a while back, the exact same one. And it didn't do these things.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No settings on anything, everything I did you see in the code I showed you. It is all my code file contains. I run it with windows normal cmd, and also I just created a new file, with something else. Uses pandas as well. Whenever I print out the head of something, it just opens that graph again. I feel like its some bug. The code never tells the program to open some graph, and they are the same numbers and graph points as before, even tho I have some absolutely different code now.

Comment: That's funny. So you don't need quandl to reproduce? Can you run [this exact sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbmO1.png) and update the question with it as well as the precise/literal output?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest running the exact code you send me returns this in the console

-Start
-Series created
0     5
1     4
dtype: int64
-Series printed



ALSO it doesnt open the graph this time

Comment: So it *does* depend on quandl. So same game [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSen2.png).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yep. (btw your first post still showed my API key. which I edited out of my OP. but it still is visible in your screenshot on your first post)
I tried the code with and only and it opens the graph again. But that makes no sense. I did the same a while back and quandl never did that

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the print statements and the exact order of outputs?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest actually I tried to edit the OP, but stack overflow doesnt let me because some stuff. But i literally told you everything that i get as results etc.

Comment: Really? Currently it's not clear to me which line in the code is responsible. That is what I'm trying to figure out. Once that is clear one can proceed with further debugging.

Comment: Btw the api key is also still visible in the revision history of the question. So you might just delete this question completely and ask a new one where you then can also use the print statements from my above comments.